# Improper integral with a dilogarithm: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}(x) \ln^{2}(1-x)}{x}~dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

> I would like to evaluate the following improper integral:
>   $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}(x) \ln^{2}(1-x)}{x}~dx$$

I don't know how to start, can I use integration by parts from the beginning?

---

My trial was to represent  $\operatorname{Li}_{2}(x)$  as a series: $$\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k^2}$$
Then, the integral becomes: $$\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k-1}\ln^2(1-x) dx $$ Then use integration by parts but which $u$ and which $dv$ and what to do after that?

Answer (score 3):

By Euler's Beta function
$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^{k-1}(1-x)^a\,dx = B(k,a+1) = \frac{\Gamma(k)\,\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(k+a+1)} \tag{1}$$
hence
$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^{k-1}\log^2(1-x)\,dx = \frac{d}{da^2}\left.\frac{\Gamma(k)\,\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(k+a+1)}\right|_{a=0} = \frac{H_k^2+H_k^{(2)}}{k}\tag{2}$$
and the wanted integral equals
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k^2+H_k^{(2)}}{k^3} = \color{red}{2\,\zeta(2)\,\zeta(3)-\zeta(5)}\approx 2.91768094545122231\tag{3}$$
by standard results on [Euler sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html).

Comment: Did you use defferntiation under integral sign?

Comment: @akibscorpion: yes I did, in order to convert $(1-x)^a$ into $\log^2(1-x)$.

Comment: And the last sums can it be solve using amaster therom of series and if you can give me a link for the evaluated sum

Comment: @akibscorpion: I have no idea about the *Master Theorem* you are mentioning, but the relevant Mathworld page on Euler sums has been linked.

Comment: @akibscorpion: did you have Cornel Ioan Valean recent paper (http://jca.ele-math.com/10-10/A-master-theorem-of-series-and-an-evaluation-of-a-cubic-harmonic-series) in mind? If so, that should be added as context to your actual question (maybe with some extra effort from your side, too. Why are you interested in such integral?)

Comment: I'm doing some reserches yes I have them sir

Comment: Can you show how the second derivative with respect to a  after substituting with a=0 comes like that

Comment: @kaderezzat: $\frac{d^2}{da^2}(1-z)^a = (1-z)^a \log^2(1-z)$ hence $$\log^2(1-z) = \left.\frac{d^2}{da^2}(1-z)^a\right|_{a=0}$$

Comment: Not that I means how it comes Hn

Comment: @kaderezzat: the digamma function, hence the harmonic numbers, come from $\Gamma'(x) = \psi(x)\,\Gamma(x)$.

Comment: can u explain more I have derivative it but I can't got Hn

Comment: $\psi(n)=H_{n-1}-\gamma$, but I am disengaging since I think you are squeezing informations on details you may work by yourself.